# Using an IF statement in Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else

I'm trying to use an if statement in the field calculator:
This is what the code looks like in Python:

```
a= 2 
FacilityID= !FACILITYID! 
if a%2==0:
   MH_ID_Calc=FacilityID[0:6]
else:
   MH_ID_Calc=FacilityID[7:14]

print MH_ID_Calc
```

> 06M244

so I tried to run that in ArcGIS field calculator:

```
def myCalc(FID,FACID):
if FID%2==0:
return FACID[0:6]
else:
return FACID[7:14]



myCalc( !FID! !FACILITYID!)
```

But it fails each time.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please check your indentation - there are no indents in your field calculator code above, but python needs the indents.  Also double-check that you've selected the Python Parser in field calculator.

Comment: What happens when you run the field calculator?  There should be result messages under Geoprocessing > Results

Comment: Check out this [question and answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81817/basic-if-then-in-python-parser-of-arcgis-field-calculator) which probably makes this a duplicate.

Comment: `myCalc(!FID!, !FACILITYID!)`? There's a comma missing when you call the function

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message.

Comment: @LEECCC Your indentation is wrong in your Field Calculator snippet, and you are missing a comma in the expression `myCalc(!FID!, !FACILITYID!)` - If you fix these, do you still get an error?  If so please [edit] your question to include the error message

Answer (score 1):

As others have already commented, the parameters of the function call in your expression should be comma separated:

```
myCalc(!FID!, !FACILITYID!)
```

And you must use correct indentation with Python (unlike other languages, this is part of Python syntax, and it will not work if the indentation is not correct):

```
def myCalc(FID,FACID):
    if FID%2==0:
        return FACID[0:6]
    else:
        return FACID[7:14]
```

Ie, anywhere that a line ends with a colon (`:`) represents a new code block and the next line should be indented further.  All lines within a block must have exactly the same indentation, unless they are part of a sub-block, in which case, they must have the exact same indentation as the other lines a the same level of that sub-block.